# On using structure literals in function and macro definitions

Tags: function, random, macros, common-lisp, literals

**IMPORTANT:** This question is motivated solely by my wanting to learn Common Lisp.  Beyond this autodidactic goal, it has no ulterior practical purpose.

---

If, at my REPL<sup>1</sup>, I evaluate the following expression

```
CL-USER> (random-state-p
  #S(random-state
       :state #.(make-array 627
                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
                            :initial-element 7)))
```

...I get `T`.  In other words, the literal

```lisp
#S(random-state
     :state #.(make-array 627
                          :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
                          :initial-element 7))
```

...evaluates to a valid `random-state` object.

---

So far so good.

Now, I try to define a function, `silly-random-state`, so that the expression `(silly-random-state 7)` will produce the same `random-state` object as that produced by the literal above, like this:

```lisp
(defun silly-random-state (some-int)
  #S(random-state
       :state #.(make-array 627
                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
                            :initial-element some-int)))
```

...but my REPL *will have none of it!*  It won't even evaluate this `defun`!  It complains that `some-int` is undefined<sup>2</sup>.

On further thought, I guess it makes sense that one cannot stick a *variable* inside a *literal* and expect the resulting expression to make sense...  Maybe I need a macro for this?

So then I try to define a *macro* that, given an integer argument, will expand to such a `random-state` object, like this:

```lisp
(defmacro silly-random-state-macro (some-int)
  `#S(random-state
        :state #.(make-array 627
                             :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
                             :initial-element ,some-int)))
```

Again, my REPL will have none of it.  The evaluation of the expression above fails with

> Comma inside backquoted structure (not a list or general vector.)

---

Each of the two failures above leads to a corresponding question:

1. how can I define a function `silly-random-state` that takes an integer `SOME-INT` as argument, and returns the `random-state` equal to the one the REPL would produce if I gave it the expression below after replacing `PLACEHOLDER` with the integer `SOME-INT`?

```lisp
#S(random-state
     :state #.(make-array 627
                          :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
                          :initial-element PLACEHOLDER))
```

2. how can I define a *macro* `silly-random-state-macro` such that `(silly-random-state-macro some-int)` expands to a the same `random-state` object described in (1)?

---

(To repeat, my motivation here is only to better understand what can and cannot be done with Common Lisp<sup>3</sup>.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> SBCL + SLIME/Emacs running on Darwin.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> BTW, my REPL had never been so picky before!  For example, it will evaluate something like `(defun foo () undefined-nonsense)`.  Granted, it does grouse a bit over the undefined variable in the body, but in the end it *will* evaluate the `defun`.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> In fact, I debated whether I should include [prng] among the tags for this question, since its topics are really literals, functions, and macros, and the role of CL's default PRNG in it is only incidental.  I finally opted to keep this tag just in case the role of the PRNG in the question is less incidental than it seems to me.</sup>

---

**EDIT**: OK, I think I found a way to define the function I described in (1); it's not very elegant, but it works:

```lisp
(defun silly-random-state (some-int)
  (read-from-string
   (format nil "#S(random-state :state #.(make-array 627 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32) :initial-element ~A))" some-int)))
```

Comment: The reader macro `#.` means evaluate at read time. In the initial cases the values were specified at read time, being fixed values. When you converted the example to `defun` the value of `some-int` is unbound at read time. It is only bound when the function is called.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is about structure literals but relies on a example that is however unfortunate (random-state). You can generally write structure literals in your code, but as said in another answer, there is no way to have backquotes inside structs literal. If I try to do so, I have an error:

> Comma inside backquoted structure (not a list or general vector.)

You have to use constructors or maybe higher-level APIs around those structs.

The only way to inject values is read-time evaluation, but as you noticed, you need to be in a reading phase, hence the use of `read-from-string`. This works but as you said not very elegant.

Besides, here you are already depending on a particular representation of the `random-state`, so you might as well use the extensions offered by SBCL, namely [`sb-ext:seed-random-state`](https://koji-kojiro.github.io/sb-docs/build/html/sb-ext/function/SEED-RANDOM-STATE.html).

This is thus how you could write a function that builds a random state given a placeholder value:

```
USER> (defun silly-random-state (some-int)
        (sb-ext:seed-random-state (make-array 627
                                              :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
                                              :initial-element some-int)))
SILLY-RANDOM-STATE
USER> (silly-random-state 5)
#S(RANDOM-STATE :STATE #.(MAKE-ARRAY 627 :ELEMENT-TYPE '(UNSIGNED-BYTE 32)
                                     :INITIAL-CONTENTS
                                     '(0 2567483615 624 2147483648 2465029273 ...)))
```

Now that you have a regular function that does not rely on read-time macros, once you have it loaded in your environment you can call it at various points of evaluation, at read-time, in macros, etc. This is not specific to random-state, *in general you should try to write regular functions, and only then choose when they are executed*.

But here you have to be careful, since a random-state is mutated when used.

In the following examples I bind `*random-state*` to force the use of a specific state for `random` (I could also pass it directly to `random`, this is not important here). The resulting function is called multiple times to show how the result changes or not.

Here the function recreates a fresh state each time, the result is always the same:

```
USER> (lambda () (let ((*random-state* (silly-random-state 3)))
                   (random 10)))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {536DDB4B}>
USER> (loop repeat 5 collect (funcall *))
(7 7 7 7 7)
```

Below, one state literal is computed and injected in the source code, thanks to read-time evaluation, but note however that different values are produced over time:

```
USER> (lambda () (let ((*random-state* #.(silly-random-state 3)))
                   (random 10)))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {536E5C7B}>
USER> (loop repeat 5 collect (funcall *))
(7 0 9 3 6)
```

This is due to the fact that `random` mutates the state. But since the state is now a literal, we entered the realm of undefined behavior. This is quite explicit in [**3.7.1 Modification of Literal Objects**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/03_ga.htm):

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects are destructively modified. For this purpose, the following operations are considered destructive:
>
> **random-state**: using it as an argument to the function **random**.

So you shouldn't be trying to have such literal objects in code.

#### load-time-value

Likewise, you could try using [`LOAD-TIME-VALUE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_ld_tim.htm) to seed the random state to a particular state. Here below I define `roll-1d6` which picks a number from 1 to 6 (inclusive). The intent is that the dice always behaves the same when loading a program, regardless of the global random state:

```
USER> (defun roll-1d6 ()
      (let ((*random-state* (load-time-value (silly-random-state 3))))
        (1+ (random 6))))
ROLL-1D6
USER> (roll-1d6)
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
USER> (roll-1d6)
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
USER> (roll-1d6)
1 (1 bit, #x1, #o1, #b1)
USER> (roll-1d6)
2 (2 bits, #x2, #o2, #b10)
USER> (roll-1d6)
4 (3 bits, #x4, #o4, #b100)
```

If I redefine it (in a different but equivalent way), the state is reset when I reload the function, and the same numbers are computed:

```
USER> (defun roll-1d6 () (1+ (random 6 (load-time-value (silly-random-state 3)))))
WARNING: redefining PARROT.USER::ROLL-1D6 in DEFUN
ROLL-1D6
USER> (roll-1d6)
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
USER> (roll-1d6)
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
USER> (roll-1d6)
1 (1 bit, #x1, #o1, #b1)
USER> (roll-1d6)
2 (2 bits, #x2, #o2, #b10)
USER> (roll-1d6)
4 (3 bits, #x4, #o4, #b100)
```

But, even though `load-time-value` allows for the resulting object to be mutable:

> If [read-only-p is] nil (the default), the result must be neither copied nor coalesced; it must be considered to be potentially modifiable data.

It also says:

> The result of this compile-time evaluation is treated as a **literal object** in the compiled code.

Also:

> If two lists (load-time-value form) that are the same under equal but are not identical are evaluated or compiled, their values always come from distinct evaluations of form. Their values may not be coalesced unless read-only-p is t.

So I am not 100% sure the example is well-defined, I think the compiler is not allowed to build and reuse a single object if there was multiple calls with the same arguments, e.g. `(silly-random-state 3)`, but the fact that the resulting object is of type `random-state` might make further operations on it undefined (?), which wouldn't be the case for example with a user-defined class.

#### let over defun

You can also precompute the state in a function as follows:

```
(let ((state (silly-random-state 3)))
  (defun roll-1d6 ()
    (1+ (random 6) state)))
```

Comment: Thank you!  One thing I am puzzled by is that the expression `(silly-random-state 7)`, where `silly-random-state` is as you defined it, using `sb-ext:seed-random-state`, evaluates to a structure whose `:state` slot is completely different from that of the structure corresponding to the literal in my post.  Specifically, the latter is an array of 627 identical integers (all 7s), whereas in the former all the array elements are different.

Comment: See: https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/target-random.lisp#L218 the buffer is mixed with some other, constant, initial state; you should call %make-random-state directly if you want to build a structure with a given buffer, but this is probably not how it is supposed to work

Comment: Thank you again.  I must say that CL's idea of "seeding" a PRNG is radically different from anything else in my experience (and I've been using PRNGs since the mid 90s, and even implemented a few back then).  I still don't get this notion of "seeding", not at all, but this would be a topic for a different thread.

Answer (score 3):

*structures* are quite tricky. They have many options and they are designed to support fast code. They are also not designed to be introspective, even though some Common Lisp implementations might support that. For example at runtime one might not get to know what slots a structure has.

There is also no *backquote syntax* for structure literals.

The *random state* is a structure in SBCL. There is a slot `state`, but it is read only.

The structure also defines a special constructor function.

We can then create one:

```
(sb-kernel::%make-random-state
  (make-array 627
              :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32)
              :initial-element 7))
```

Your solution with read-from-string is okay. One reason for using read-time evaluation with `#.`, is that the specialized vector has no exact printed representation. Means, that there is no way to represent the element-type in a printed representation of the vector.

Comment: Thank you!  Through this exercise, I have become particularly curious about the general question of defining macros that expand to literals, particularly to structure literals.  Should I take it from your answer that there is no way to write a macro that expands to the literal I described in my post?